# how to use DES algorithm to encrypt or decrypt some data in object-c？

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Now I want to encrypt or decrypt some data in object-c use DES algorithm ,can somebody give me some suggestion?

Comment: Do you have the option of encrypting the data with a more secure algorithm like AES?  DES has been shown to be insecure. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard.  Are you planning to encrypt the data as you send it or are you planning to encrypt and store the data on the phone?

Answer (score 1):

First point. AES has replaced DES as the de-facto encrpytion standard, at least for the banking industry.

Second Point: Irrespective of what algo you decide on, this is what you have to do.

1. Add the Security.framework to your project.
2. Import the "CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h" file. This contains all the interfaces for symmetric encryption.
3. Using the methods in this class, you can define your encryption algo (AES, DES, etc.), the key size, padding that you want to use, etc.
4. You have to option of a one-shot API for encryption/decryption (CCCrypt()) or more advanced options if needed.

Hope this helps. Let me know if you need any particular information.

Comment: Any details example,I don't know how to use it

Comment: details... details please! I have a very old ntlm authentication code that uses DES ebb - but using openSSL APIs. Now openSSL was finally removed from MacOS (as well as iOS long time ago) So I must convert the code to use the commonCrypto APIs - but I find it hard, since I'm not familiar with encryption parameters, algorithms etc... so a small sample will be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A code sample can be found in [How to encrypt an NSString in Objective C with DES in ECB-Mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512184/how-to-encrypt-an-nsstring-in-objective-c-with-des-in-ecb-mode)

As the referring topic describes, you will have to keep in mind that DES uses a 56-bit (7 bytes) key and 64-bit (8 bytes) blocks.

Although DES is symmetric you will have to decrypt data by providing the kCCDecrypt option to the CCCrypt function.