# Is there any API that could use to call the DES encrypt and decrypt in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

Is there any API that could use to call the DES encrypt and decrypt  in objective-c?

Comment: This is the second time you’re duplicating your own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601347

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL (built-in on the Mac, [get it here for iPhone](https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone)) has [all the DES_* functions you could want](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/des.html) for encryption and decryption.